# What was Kakashi's name when he was in the Anbu?

Tags: naruto

I want to know what Kakashi's name was in the Anbu because Yamato's real name is Tenzo which is very different.

Comment: In a lot of fanfiction, he's referred to as Hound as his code name, but at the moment I can't find anything indicating whether that's canon or just particularly pervasive fanon.

Comment: came here to ask the same question along with itachi's haha

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure Kakashi's code name was never revealed or touched upon as I've seen pretty much the entire series.

Fanfics do have names such as Hound but nothing shows that I was ever mentioned in the anime or manga or even any light novel.

Kishimoto Sensei might've answered a question in an interview (highly unlikely though) but I haven't seen any evidence for that yet too

Also I read on this [Yahoo Answer](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/amp/qna/20150827160228AAC5yF0?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAABDer0-cdvl8ZScVkh6rYM7JdySOq4sHo8_g3GBAit3cDhK_S_ijcA3Q3eZSic2jqfOWVaXiwfZBvlpTfxG38cOclZB7zUv7VZcq0LDCQ8zTleuCnwuvTi7ISV8kCdEAh6gs-8jcFTejQBMHh5B63FS63GJ9t8N-m73ipPBCWjqG) that names were usually changed after the missions but I couldn't find anything supporting this assertion.

Comment: @doradora you're welcome buddy and amigo would've been better 